# React useFetch hook + onclick / event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom reusable hook to make an http call that I created, I'm using it in my component as follows:

```
const { data, error, isLoading, executeFetch } = useHttp<IArticle[]>('news', []);
```

In the same component, I have an option to toggle a checkbox. When the checkbox is toggled, I want to execute another API call:

```
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        useHttp('news');
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.articleListHeader}>
                <h1>Article List</h1>
                <small className={classes.headerSubtitle}>{data.length} Articles</small>
            </div>
            <ul>
                {data.map(article => <Article article={article} handleChange={handleChange}/>)}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
```

But as hooks behave, I can't run hooks outside react function component directly.

What's the solution / best practise for this?

Comment: You can't call the hook inside a nested function in your component. Your hook should return a function that you can use to make the HTTP request. I believe `executeFetch` should be called from inside of the `handleChange` function.

Comment: What is the second parameter to `useHttp` there for where you pass an array? Is that something like a dependency array or are this initial values?

Comment: @trixn initial values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to use hooks like that. They should always be on the top level and probably be called/recalculated only when the dependencies change (so for example the API call parameters passed). However, I can see that you have `executeFetch` returned from the hook. Can't you  just call that? So

```js
const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  executeFetch();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve that:

1. Pass the `checked` value to the hook as a parameter. This is
   preferred if the checked value is changing how the request is
   executed. It may e.g. be used as a query parameter. In order for that  to work your hook has to accept parameters in some way that will be used as query parameters.
2. Let the hook return a function to re-fetch that you can call in your
   handler. It seems like `executeFetch` might already be that function?